# Prove that convex set has empty interior if and only of there exists a hyperplane containing the set.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I was reading about the convex set and its various properties. I came up with a theorem but don't know how to prove it.

***Theorem:*** A convex set has empty interior if and only if there is a hyperplane containing the set.

Someone please give an idea how to prove it.

Comment: Is your convex set $S$ in $\Bbb R^n$? If so, here's an outline. Pick distinct points $p_0,p_1\in S$. Since $S$ isn't contained in the line through $p_0,p_1$, pick a point $p_2\in S$ that's not in that line. Since $S$ isn't contained in the plane through $p_0,p_1,p_2$, pick a point $p_3\in S$ that's not in that plane. And so on until you have $p_0,\dots,p_n$. Then $S$ contains the simplex with those points as vertices, which has empty interior.

Comment: could you please explain the last line more clearly.... What is the mean that S contain simplex of these points which has empty interior

Comment: consider the affine hull of that convex set and the maximal hyperplane that contains it